# How to Record rules to base on user login relation with Many2Many

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to develop my knowledge. Then I make a personal project name "My Recruitment". 
I've inherited model "hr.applicant" and add new field name "x_place". 
I'd like to limit the user to see only the record that user is a member of Many2Many name "my.recruitment.place".

I'm creating Record Rules with the following

It's working fine with my test ir.rule

```
['|',('x_place','in',[1,2,3,4]),('x_place','=',False)]
```

but I expect the result

```
xxx = self.env['my.recruitment.place'].search([('res_users_id','=',user.id)])

['|',('x_place','in',[xxx]),('x_place','=',False)]
```

Here is my class:

```
class MYRecruitment(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['hr.applicant']
    x_place = fields.Many2one('my.recruitment.place', "Place")


class MyRecruitmentPlace(models.Model):
    _name = "my.recruitment.place"
    _description = "Place of Recruitment"
    _sql_constraints = [
        ('name_uniq', 'unique (name)', 'The name of the place of Recruitment must be unique!')
    ]

    name = fields.Char("Place", required=True, translate=True)
    user_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users', string="Owners")
    sequence = fields.Integer("Sequence", default=1, help="Gives the sequence order when displaying a list of place.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
['|',('x_place','in',xxx.ids),('x_place','=',False)]
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
@api.multi
def _place_get(self):
    return self.search([])
```

Rule Definition (Domain Filter):

```
['|',('user_id', '=', user.id),('x_place','in',[_place_get.ids])]
```

Error:

```
ValueError: <class 'NameError'>: "name '_place_get' is not defined" while evaluating
"['|',('user_id', '=', user.id),('x_place','in',[_place_get.ids])]"
```